# How to show a LoadingDialog only if the operation takes too long?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I do an `API` call in my Android App which can return a response almost immediatly or take a bit longer, before the `API` call i show my `LoadingDialog` and on response i dismiss it, the big issue of that is even if the response is immediate i show and dismiss the `LoadingDialog` and it seems like a "bug" as the screen shows and hides immediatly a dialog.

I would be able to show that dialog ONLY if the response take longer than 1 second to be returned.

Here is my code:

```
   public void AlertLoading() {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LoadingDialog.TAG);
        if (fragment instanceof LoadingDialog) {
            ((LoadingDialog) fragment).dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        }else {
            new LoadingDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), LoadingDialog.TAG);
        }
    }

    private void getTable(String tableNumber) {


        AlertLoading();

        Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://" + ip + "/webquery/?FINDTAV=" + tableNumber + "&v2=true")
                .setTimeout(10000)
                .asString()
                .setCallback((e, result) -> {
                    AlertLoading();
                    // DOING STUFF
                });
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. What if the response take 1.1 second? it still looks like your original situation. You never know how long a request would take until it actually finishes.

Comment: @RickyMo 1 second was just an example i'd probably was going to set it based on some tests about the response time, but almost most of requests are just "check requests" which are very fast and has no data.

Comment: If you have prior knowledge of which requests are fast, just don't make a dialog for those requests according to your prior knowledge. But you never know the network condition of the client.

Comment: @RickyMo oh i can't know it, the request is the same but for some i just ask the server smth like "are there any data?" and the server can respond with "NO" or with a large data, the "NO" response is the fastest and the one with large JSON is the slower.

Comment: If the problem is a loading dialog with short duration looks weird, better off make a "minimum duration" for the loading dialog so that it doesn't look weird.

Comment: If the json data is that large that it make a noticeable different, you can send a HEAD request to query for the Content-Length before sending the GET request.

Comment: @RickyMo love both solutions, will try both of them, thank you.

Comment: This is essentially the problem that [`ContentLoadingProgressBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/ContentLoadingProgressBar) sets out to address.

Comment: @RickyMo just made an answer with one of your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Ricky Mo in comments i've followed the way of checking for Content-Lenght and if this is > than X bytes i'm showing the loading dialog.

I changed the code as following:

```
    private void getTable(String tableNumber) {

    // Doing an API call with HEAD method which returns Content-Lenght, if this is > than 10000 i'm showing the dialog



LoadingDialog.RetrofitClient.getInstance(ip).getApi().getTableLenght(tableNumber, true)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Void> call, @NonNull retrofit2.Response<Void> response) {
                            String contentLength = response.headers().get("Content-Length");
                            if (contentLength != null) { 
                                if (Double.parseDouble(contentLength) > 10000) { 
                                    showLoading(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Void> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                            showLoading(false);
                        }
                    });
    
    // I've changed Ion with Retrofit for data parsing
        
Call<String> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance(ip).getApi().getTable(tableNumber, true);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {
                    showLoading(false);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                     ... Doing stuff
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    showLoading(false);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flows to receive api response and collect it inside coroutines

```
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    repo.myApiFunc(param1, param2)
                        .onStart {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                uiState.value = UiState.ProgressBar(true)
                            }
                        }
                        .catch {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                uiState.value = UiState.ProgressBar(false)
                            }
                        }
                        .collect { response->
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                uiState.value = UiState.ProgressBar(false)
                                handleData(response)
                            }
                        }
                }
```

And Your repository function looks like this

```
suspend fun myApiFunc(param1: Any, param2: Any
    ): Flow<MyResponse> {
        return flow<MyResponse> {
            emit(apiHelper.apiCall(param1, param2))
        }
    }
```

and in your api call looks like

```
    @POST("Endpoint")
    suspend fun apiCall(
        @Field("email") email: String,
        @Field("password") password: String
    ): MyResponse
```

and your uistate variable is also of flow type that is collected inside fragment and displays the loader on receiving true while hides it on false